# I can't uderstand, Mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am new to MYSQL and I want to make this query but I don't know how to write it the right way, so I will be very pleased if you guys help me with that one.

```
SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $skip, $perPage WHERE post_id = $page
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $page LIMIT $skip, $perPage ` Is what you are looking for

Comment: There's an order in the query structrue, LIMIT should be the last `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $page LIMIT $skip, $perPage
`

Comment: place limit at end. also look at w3schools. SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $page  LIMIT $skip, $perPage

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **LIMIT** after **WHERE**

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $page LIMIT $skip, $perPage;
```

Comment: This answer should not be upvoted, because `LIMIT` -- in the context of pagination -- should only be used with `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ORDER BY` if you are using pagination. Otherwise you risk to get rows with undefined order.

Per SQL definition, a `SELECT` statement returns the rows in no particular order by default. If you need a particular ordering you **need** to specify it using `ORDER BY`.

The answer should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $page 
  ORDER BY recorded_at
  LIMIT $skip, $perPage;
```

Please note I added `ORDER BY recorded_at` to ensure the data will make sense to the end user.